# How to create a plot function when the title differ?

Tags: r, function, title

I want to create a map of France and to make appear different points on different maps.

The code is quite easy to do :

```
library(raster)

#mydata
pointA <- data.frame(longitude = c(5.819472,5.384418 ),
                   latitude = c(46.11558, 46.18197))
pointC <- data.frame (longitude = 4.218322,
                     latitude = 44.20379)


cartes <- function(point){
 france <- getData('GADM', country = 'FRA', level = 1) # Map of France
 plot(france, border = "red", main = "Name of the point") 
 points(point$longitude, point$latitude)
}

cartes(pointA)
cartes(pointC)
```

But I can't manage to find a way to change the title according to the name of the point...

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ensym()` might help you :

```
library(raster)

#mydata
pointA <- data.frame(longitude = c(5.819472,5.384418 ),
                     latitude = c(46.11558, 46.18197))
pointC <- data.frame (longitude = 4.218322,
                      latitude = 44.20379)


cartes <- function(point){
  france <- getData('GADM', country = 'FRA', level = 1) # Map of France
  plot(france, border = "red", main = ensym(point)) 
  points(point$longitude, point$latitude)
}

cartes(pointA)
cartes(pointC)
```